# Cannot browse external website with IE8 but still can with Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-options

since yesterday at my workplace, I could no longer visit any external sites apart from within the company Intranet with IE8 any more, this also applies with Chrome. Which left me Firefox being the only browser I can use for browsing external sites. I tried restarting my computer several times; reinstalling IE, but no luck with any of these approaches. I've also done some google search, found out that it could have being caused by virus that's affecting the internet options settings for IE, as firefox don't share the settings with IE which probably explain why I can still use Firefox. But the question is, what are the settings? And do I get my IE working again? Thanks in advance

Comment: IE8? *shudders* Try resetting your settings on both Chrome and IE.

Comment: You should ask this question in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE and Chrome makes use of the same settings under Control Panel -> Internet Options
Where as for Firefox, this is separate.

Since this is at your workplace, it is likely that it is related to the proxy configuration.

Comment: Thanks for you response. In fact there was no proxy configuration settings at my workplace. In fact I never touch any part of the settings since day one.

Comment: Lewis you're right, it's the proxy settings. Thanks mate problem solved!